# How to check whether a time is between particular range?

Tags: java, date, timestamp

I need to check whether current time is between 8 AM and 3 PM or not. If it is between those time range, then I need to return yes otherwise return false.

```
boolean isNowBetweenDateTime(final Date s, final Date e) {
    final Date now = new Date();
    return now.after(s) && now.before(e);
}
```

But I am not sure I should be using `Date` here? Can I just not use timestamp and check timestamp accordingly? What is the right way to do this?

I am still on Java 7.

Comment: To paraphrase the excuse to start drinking, "it's always between 8am and 3pm somewhere in the world". For one thing, you need to specify a timezone in which to evaluate the local time.

Comment: I don't know that there is a 'right' way to do this. java.util.Date will work just fine, but you may want to look into java.time.ZonedDateTime, which will help with the time zone problem @AndyTurner pointed out

Comment: @AndyTurner time zone will be PDT

Comment: @user1950349 all year round? Or do you mean e.g. America/Los_Angeles? Irrespective of your reply, know that Date has no timezone information, so you might not always get the result you expect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using a version of Java prior to Java 8, take a look at the API documentation for [Joda](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/).

Specifically, there is an [AbstractInterval#containsNow()](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/base/AbstractInterval.html#containsNow--) method which will allow you to do what you want.

For example:

```
new Interval(start, end).containsNow();
```

where start and end can either be any of a number of different values/objects. See the documentation for the different constructors available: [Interval](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Interval.html)

---

You could modify your method to be like so:

```
boolean isNowBetweenDateTime(final DateTime s, final DateTime e) {
    return new Interval(s, e).containsNow();
}
```

That said, it's only one line, so you really shouldn't need to wrap it with your own method :)

Again, take a look at the documentation. The Interval constructor can take a variety of objects/values, so pick whichever suits your needs. I recommend DateTime since it seems to best describe what you're looking to do.

Comment: Two years on from the release of Java 8, the first port of call should be the Java 8 time API.

Comment: @AndyTurner Some of us still need to use older versions of Java :) But fair point nonetheless, I've edited my answer.

Comment: I am still on java 7. Sorry forgot to mention in the question. Can you provide an example with java 7?

Comment: @user1950349 Edited with a more complete example.

Comment: @avojak ohh I see now. I thought Interval was Java 8 that's why I said that.. Can you also tell me how I can initialize `s` as 8 AM and `e` as 3 PM here. I have never used Joda so slightly confused.

Comment: Assuming you want this to work every day, and not just a specific day, you could do: `final DateTime s = new DateTime().withHourOfDay(8).withMinuteOfHour(0).withSecondOfMinute(0).withMillisOfSecond(0);` This will explicitly set the hour,minute,second,millisecond fields to be 8am on the dot, whereas the year,month,day fields will adjust with whatever day it currently is. For 3pm, you can use 15 instead of 8 (24-hour time).

Answer (score 2):

## java.time

You are using old outmoded classes. They have been supplanted by the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). Much of the functionality has been back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further adapted to Android in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).

### `LocalTime`

The [`LocalTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html) class actually truly represents a time-of-day only value, unlike the old `java.sql.Time` and `java.util.Date` classes.

```
LocalTime start = LocalTime.of( 8 , 0 );
LocalTime stop = LocalTime.of( 15 , 0 );
```

### Time zone

Determining the current time requires a time zone. For any given moment the time varies around the globe by time zone.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
LocalTime now = LocalTime.now( zoneId );
```

### Compare

Compare by calling `equals`, isAfter, or isBefore. We use the Half-open approach here as is common in date-time work where the beginning is *inclusive* while the ending is *exclusive*.

```
 Boolean isNowInRange = ( ! now.isBefore( start ) ) && now.isBefore( stop ) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Joda Time** is a pretty straightforward library to be used, and if you define the comparison date objects as **LocalDate**, then you can use the isBefore(), isAfter() boolean methods: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#isBefore-java.time.chrono.ChronoLocalDateTime-
Hope it helps!

Answer (score -1):

Using Date for the current time is fine.  There's a few ways you can go about it.

```
1. System.currentTimeInMillis()

2. Date today = new Date()
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question. He doesn't need to print the date.